# How to set 7z compression level using GUI in Ubuntu?

Tags: gui, archive, compression, 7zip, file-roller

Archive Manager, or `file-roller`, doesn't seem to have the option to set the compression level for `7z` files.

[image]

However, the windows client [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has an option to do so using GUI -

[image]

On Ubuntu/Linux, one can set the compression level in the command line (CLI) using the `-m` flag. For details, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491223/7z-ultra-settings-for-zip-format/491243#491243).

Is there any provision for setting the compression level for `7z` archives using GUI in Ubuntu?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it uses the `ultra` level, by default!

Comment: @blade19899 The default level is 5 (Normal)

Comment: You schooled me. The only option is by using the commandline version. And submit a feature request! To the best of my knowledge :)

Comment: I think it's about the same algorithm as xz normally uses, and the higher compression levels could require "several gigabytes" of ram (so says `man xz`) - It's not like zip where specifying "max" all the time is the best idea.

Comment: That depends on the size of the files to be archived. For practical purposes, the RAM requirement is not much of an issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My idea was to find some hint in the file listing of the packages or in gconf, but I had no luck. Someone else knew the answer though.

### Superuser: [Change default compression levels for file-roller?](https://superuser.com/a/831840/252532)

> Either:
>
> ```
> $ dconf write /org/gnome/file-roller/general/compression-level "'maximum'"
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> $ dconf-editor
> ```
>
> 1. Select `org` in the left-hand pane.
> 2. Select `gnome` in the left-hand pane.
> 3. Select `file-roller` in the left-hand pane.
> 4. Select `general` in the left-hand pane.
> 5. Select `compression-level` in the right-hand pane.
> 6. Set `compression-level` to `'maximum'`.
>
> Unfortunately, you cannot fine-tune this setting for different
>   compression programmes. If you want all the freedom, you can use your
>   shell instead.
>
> [Image of dconf Editor with file-roller's compression-level set to
>   maximum.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOdjK.png).

That answer previously had no upvotes, so I checked if this has any effect at all and choose to compress some documents with the default settings and with maximum settings (type 7z). Result: 2,3 KB improvement on a ~300 KB archive.

**Caution:**

- Depending on the content it can have a negative impact to compress everything with LZMA/LZMA2 on level maximum. PNGs for example are already compressed with Deflate and won't gain much from compression. It would make more sense to optimize them with PNGOUT/OptiPNG, [Zopfli](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zopfli) and then archive them with [LZ4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=liblz4-tool), achieving faster archive decompression and reducing file size.

---

I tried to find out more through file-rollers manpage and [user manual](https://help.gnome.org/users/file-roller/stable/), still no luck. Then I dowloaded the source package and searched for "maximum" in `fr-command-7z.c` (note how I avoid to say I *read* the source), which gave me the following:

```c
switch (archive->compression) {
case FR_COMPRESSION_VERY_FAST:
    fr_process_add_arg (command->process, "-mx=1");
    break;
case FR_COMPRESSION_FAST:
    fr_process_add_arg (command->process, "-mx=5");
    break;
case FR_COMPRESSION_NORMAL:
    fr_process_add_arg (command->process, "-mx=7");
    break;
case FR_COMPRESSION_MAXIMUM:
    fr_process_add_arg (command->process, "-mx=9");
    if (! _g_mime_type_matches (archive->mime_type, "application/zip")
        && ! _g_mime_type_matches (archive->mime_type, "application/x-cbz"))
    {
        fr_process_add_arg (command->process, "-m0=lzma2");;
    }
    break;
}
```

That's as far as I can currently get, it seems like there is no ultra setting.

Comment: Although the method suggested may improve the compression levels, it requires the user to change values in the dconf-editor each time a different level is required. Is there any method where the compression levels are selected dynamically?

Comment: +1 for the answer. Although it does not exactly solve the problem, it provides an alternative solution.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan I understand what you mean. I'm trying not to blame anyone here, but I think that is how default Gnome applications are intended to work: you can enable hidden features but you won't find a lot of checkboxes and dropdown menus.

Comment: I guess you are right. I may try to file a feature request, maybe to be included under advanced options. Thanks :-)

Comment: This answer also seems to work on ArchLinux, where the default compression level in file-roller already is `'maximum'`. Setting to `'fast'` makes it behave like `-mx=5` which is the [cli default](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu community (not Canonical) do offer you [`ark`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/ark) in the **universe** repository.

[image]